# Proving that forall a, b in {R} |√|a| - √|b|| ≤ √|a-b|

Tags: real-analysis

Can anybody help me prove this one 
 forall a, b in {R} |√|a| - √|b|| ≤  √|a-b|
i already know how to prove 
||a| - |b|| ≤  |a-b|

but i'm stuck onthis one because it has a square root on it

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
|a - b| \geq \big||a| - |b|\big| = \left|\sqrt{|a|} - \sqrt{|b|}\right|\cdot\left|\sqrt{|a|} + \sqrt{|b|}\right| \geq \left(\sqrt{|a|} - \sqrt{|b|}\right)^2
$$

Comment: +1. You do not actually need $\lvert a\rvert > \lvert b \rvert$ here.

Comment: Agreed. It follows from the triangle inequality. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

It results from the triangle inequality:
$$\lvert a\rvert\le \lvert a-b\rvert +\lvert b\rvert$$
and the easily checked
$$\sqrt{x+y}\le \sqrt x+\sqrt y\qquad\forall\: x,y\ge0.$$